# Angular 2+ Service for getting application changes and uploading to server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am working on an Angular 4 project and I'm a bit stuck on how to implement the following.

**Steps:**

> 1. User uses the application and things change on it
> 2. These changes are saved locally using localStorage
> 3. A Service listens for changes in the data and if there are changes it uploads the changes to the server.

My idea behind saving the data locally is that the user doesn't have to get involved on sending the data to the server and also if the serve was to go offline, the user can still continue working via the local data available.

My question is...Is this a good idea or are there better ways of doing this with Angular ?

Comment: You might use `ngOnChanges`? or `NgDoCheck`, depend how the situation you want to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is good, here are steps to implement it:

1、Create a storage service, e.g. StorageService, to save data in localStorage

2、Create a update service, e.g. UpdateService, to get data from localStorage and upload to server

3、In StorageService, every time the data changed, call UpdateService

4、In UpdateService, you can detect whether network is online or offline, and you probably want a lastUpdateTime field, to record the last time when you successfully update the data to server, so you can control the frequency of update

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make an entry in the server first, if you do not have a network or your save call to server fails your local storage will never have the correct data. My suggestion will be,

1. User uses the application and things change on it,
2. A Service listens for changes in the data and if there are changes it uploads the changes to the server.
3. if above call succeed save it in  your LocalStorage,

still if you wish to save the data I suggest you try to keep it away from the view logic.